# NP completeness of a variant of assignment problem

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms, computational-complexity, np-complete

I have the following variant of assignment problem:

Suppose we have $m$ machines and $n$ jobs. Each machine is capable of doing a subset of jobs and each machine $i$ has capacity $C_i$. Each job $j$ has a load of $D_j$ and the goal is to find if there exists a satisfying assignment where each job is assigned to one machine and no machine's load exceeds its capacity.

Hence the input is: $m$ positive numbers $C_1,...,C_m$, $n$ positive numbers $D_1,...,D_n$ and the knowledge of whether machine $i$ is capable of job $j$ for all $i,j$.

This variant is a bit different from original assignment problem as now each machine is only capable of a certain subset of jobs. I personally believe it is NP complete, however,  I am not able to prove it...

Comment: When you say "each machine is capable of doing a subset of jobs," do you mean that each machine is tasked with some number of the $n$ jobs, or that each machine has its own subset of the jobs which it is able to perform?

Comment: This looks like it can be solved with Min-Cost MaxFlow: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem

Comment: @Sudix minimum-cost flow might violate the "each job is assigned to one machine" rule.